# How to access key in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I know it's possible to traverse a dictionary by using `iteritems()` or `keys()`. But what if I got a list of dics such as: `l = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]` and I want to compose a string using its keys, e.g., `s = 'a, b, c'`?

One solution is to copy all the keys into a list in advance, and compose the string I want. Just wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: @GregS: That's not what this question is about.

Comment: @GregS It's a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary contains multiple items

Comment: @NiklasB. How can you be so sure? The description says list of dics but the example is a single dict.

Comment: @GregS: It's absolutely NOT a single dict (but I have to admit that I also only saw that on second glance :)

Comment: @NiklasB. <sheepish> .. you're right! It took me 4 glances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for it and make use of the fact that iterating over a dict will yield its keys.

```
import itertools
lst = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}] 
print ', '.join(itertools.chain(*lst))
```

This also works it there are dicts with more than one element.

If you do not want duplicate elements, use a set:

```
print ', '.join(set(itertools.chain(*lst)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each dictionary will only have a single key:

```
', '.join(a.keys()[0] for a in l)
```

if not, maybe something like:

```
>>> l = [{'a': 1, 'd': 4}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
>>> ', '.join(', '.join(a.keys()) for a in l)
'a, d, b, c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the dictionaries and then over the keys of each dictionary:

```
>>> lst = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
>>> ', '.join(key for dct in lst for key in dct.keys())
'a, b, c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ''.join([i.keys()[0] for i in l])
```

You can put any delimiter you want inside of the quotes.  Just bear in mind that the dictionary isn't ordered, so you may get weird looking strings as a result of this.